# Changing App name

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

Is it possible to change the name of an app which is already in the windows 8 store through an update ? I can imagine that the actual name can be changed through the manifest file but what about the name in the store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an guide on MSDN about the things you have to do to change the name of your app:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868182.aspx

Tried it myself and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be possible - the app name is determined by the name in App Manifest. The only problem might be if the new name is already taken by someone else.

Comment: Will it change the name in the windows store as well - on the download page ?